# Where do instance methods come from on the number 1

Tags: ruby, class

The number `1` contains 109 additional methods above and beyond the `Fixnum` class it inherits from.

```
1.methods - Fixnum.methods => [:%, :&, :*, :**, :+, :+@, :-, :-@, ...]
(1.methods - Fixnum.methods).count => 109 
1.is_a? Fixnum => true
```

So from my understanding, I would say the number `1` is an instance of `Fixnum`. But why does the number `1` have so many more methods than `Fixnum`? And where do they come from? How would I write my own method for the number `1`?

Comment: Do `1.class` which returns Parent Class. here it's `Fixnum`

Comment: Right, but for example, where does the `:nonzero?` method come from? It exists within `1.methods` but not within `Fixnum.methods`

Comment: Your logic is inconsistent: you call `methods` on `1` and expect it to return the methods that you can call on `1` and you call methods on `Fixnum` and expect it to return *not* the methods that you can call on `Fixnum` but instead the methods that you can call on *instances* of `Fixnum`, for example `1`. Why would you *both* `1.methods` *and* `Fixnum.methods` to return the methods that can be called on `1`?

Comment: Since you specifically asked about the `nonzero?` method, why don't you try it out yourself: `1.nonzero?` works, but `Fixnum.nonzero?` raises a `NoMethodError`, that's why `Fixnum.methods` does not include `nonzero?`, because you cannot call `nonzero?` on `Fixnum`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `.methods`, it gives the methods defined *on that instance*. So when you ask for `Fixnum.methods`, you get the methods you can call on `Fixnum` *the class*, not on objects of type `Fixnum`.

As to your last question, Ruby allows you to extend a class like so:

```
class Fixnum
  def plus9
    return self + 9
  end
end
```

Comment: This is correct, my previous answer was not. I've added another though.

Answer (score 1):

They can come from `Fixnum`'s parent classes as well as any modules mixed in along the way. You can use `1.method('<method name>').inspect` to find out where exactly does the method originate.

`method#source_location` is good as well, but it doesn't work for native methods, which is almost everything on `1`.

Comment: Cool! `1.method(:nonzero?).inspect => "#<Method: Fixnum(Numeric)#nonzero?>" ` Could you explain this a little bit more?

Comment: This is incorrect. `methods` includes inherited methods.

Comment: @thedanotto In this case, `nonzero?` is directly defined on `Fixnum` itself.  If you look at something like `to_json`, you'll see a different result: `"#<Method: Fixnum(JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Fixnum)#to_json>"`

Comment: @JohnColanduoni: This refers to finding the source of a method using `method`. Not `methods`.

Comment: @fylooi "They can come from Fixnum's parent classes as well as any modules mixed in along the way." This is not true. That is not the reason for the difference in number of methods.

Comment: @JohnColanduoni: How so? Inherited methods come from parent classes no?

Comment: @fylooi Yes, but `methods` includes inherited methods, so that can't be the reason for the difference in the two numbers. The question is why the two lists are different, and your answer is not correct.

Comment: @JohnColanduoni: The main question I'm answering is where instance methods on `1` originate. Let's leave this here since this discussion is not helping the answer.

Comment: @fylooi No the question is "But why does the number 1 have so many more methods than Fixnum?". Every line of the question except the last one references the difference, with the context that the list of methods is obtained using `methods`. You specifically say that the extra methods can come from the base classes in the first line of your answer. The reason this is not helping the answer is that you refuse to fix it.

Comment: @thedanotto No you didn't, at most you asked two. fylooi just doesn't like admitting he made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`Fixnum` itself is an instance of `Class`, when you call `Fixnum.methods`, it returns the methods that the `Class` class and its ancestors have.

So `1.methods - Fixnum.methods` has little sense as you are comparing the methods of `Fixnum` class and the methods of `Class` class.

```
Fixnum.class
# => Class
1.class
# => Fixnum
```

> How would I write my own method for the number 1

You can implement your own methods in `Fixnum` or any of its ancestor classes: `Integer`, `Numeric`, etc, depending on which class this method makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You may misunderstand the [Object#methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-methods) method.

1. According to the Ruby API,

   > methods(regular=true) → Returns a list of the names of public and protected methods of obj.
2. So `Fixnum.methods` returns the methods from the perspective of the object, not the class.
3. [Module#instance_methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods) is what you want

   ```
   1.methods.count == Fixnum.instance_methods.count # => true
   ```

To get the right method list in Ruby is kind of a confusing thing, [Idiosyncratic Ruby](http://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/categories/) has a detailed post about [method-lists](http://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/25-meta-methodology.html#method-lists). It helps me sort things up, and hope this can help you, too.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the Fixnum class and add/modify your own methods. You can use this code:

```
class Fixnum
     def newNum_method
         puts self.methods
     end
end
```

Also you can modify existing methods the same way. Many times the 'to_s' is modified to produce specific results for example:

```
class Array
     def to_s
         puts self.join(":")
     end
 end
```

This code ONLY modifies what you specify.
You can also add class specific code for example:

```
def Array.newMethod
      puts Array.methods
end
```

This allows you to call:

```
puts Array.newMethod
```

(Which would technically be the same as "puts Array.methods")
but you can customize this to say or do whatever with the 'Array' class

You could even create a method for the Fixnum class itself to Iterate over its parents and list EACH method from them.

```
def Fixnum.listParentMethods
      .....
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
1.methods - Fixnum.instance_methods
```

and you'll get an empty array.

In ruby, classes are **objects of type `Class`**.
When you call `obj.methods`, it returns all public methods of `obj`.
So what if `obj` is a class?